# Can I disable a combobox in WinForms without graying it out?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, controls

Is there a way to disable value change for a combo box without graying it out in windows forms? I saw a few posts but they were for WPF and didnt help my situation.

Comment: If you just want to reject changes - then handle the appropriate methods and do so.

Comment: So you want a combo box that looks normal, but the user can't interact with it?  How are you going to indicate to the user that it is in this unusable state?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Graying out the combo box is the way the user knows that it is disabled and they can't modify it. A combo box that *looks* enabled, but ignores a user's attempts to edit it, is nothing short of confusing. I'd call that interface **broken**.

Comment: calm down guys i just want to know if its possible. And it really doesnt matter if its a good idea or not since its what the customer wants. they dont like it gray. in the end you have to give them what they want..

Comment: If the user can't change it, why use a combobox? It should be a label. A combobox implies *choices*. (And the customer isn't always right - sometimes they're just lacking education, and providing that can be part of your job.)

Comment: its hooked up to an edit screen. so when its in edit mode you can use it. but when they click save its read only and not editable.

Comment: Well, the reason I suggested *strongly reconsidering* whether or not this is a good idea is because it's not very easy to implement. You have to owner-draw the entire control. It's *possible*, but Windows doesn't make it easy for the reasons that have been mentioned. It's your job as a programmer to explain to the customer what's wrong with what they're asking for. They probably don't realize it; other people have handled this decision for them before. Once they get a prototype, though, they'll see how difficult it is to figure out when the box is editable and when its not.

Comment: @Cody agreed, but sometimes it is practically impossible when you add some management + customer + budget + company to the problem. In one of my past experiences we had to implement a drop down which shoots horizontal if (technically not a drop down **shoot side**) and the reason is customer was evaluating our ability to deliver and we were startup, and needed to do whatever it takes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting these on your `comobobox` will do the trick you are looking for, Combo is enabled but nobody can change or type anything so Appearance = Enabled, Behaviour = Disabled :)

```
        comboBox1.DropDownHeight = 1;
        comboBox1.KeyDown += (s, e) => e.Handled = true;
        comboBox1.KeyPress += (s, e) => e.Handled = true;
        comboBox1.KeyUp += (s, e) => e.Handled = true;
```

If for some reason you cannot use lambdas then following handlers can be associated. Right Click -> Paste has to be handled additionally if you have DropDownStyle = DropDown.

```
    //void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    e.Handled = true;
    //}

    //void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    e.Handled = true;
    //}

    //void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    e.Handled = true;
    //}
```

Comment: What happens if I use the mouse?

Comment: To re-enable instead of `true`; use a bool variable to store your enabled/ disabled state in lambdas or event handlers. and set DropDownHeight to something like 100 or 200 whatever looks good. `e.Handled = someBoolVar;` instead of `e.Handled = true;`

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar: Uh, yes it is. The combobox can still get the focus, and I can still change the selected item by rotating the scroll wheel.

Comment: I tested for wheel rotation, its not letting me select, can you share your code using some scratch location,

Comment: To disable `Paste` you can create a fake empty context menu and assign it to the combobox.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. I am disabling a combobox and I want it to turn grey but it remains white. How do I make it turn grey without messing with colors?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the focus to the next control in the `Enter` handler, makes the ComboBox entirely resistant to clicks and is exactly what I needed.

The `comboBox1.DropDownHeight = 1;` in the accepted answer shows a weird one-pixel dropdown that looks kinda broken to my UI-sensitive eyes.

The only disadvantage I've found is that one can't Shift-Tab across the field but in my case that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Then save his handlers as variables and simply -= them after.

Example:

```
var keyDown = (s, e) => e.Handled = true;
var keyPress = (s, e) => e.Handled = true;
var keyUp = (s, e) => e.Handled = true;
```

Then replace in his with:

```
comboBox1.KeyDown += keyDown;
comboBox1.KeyPress += keyPress;
comboBox1.KeyUp += keyUp;
```

Then when you want to remove:

```
comboBox1.KeyDown -= keyDown;
comboBox1.KeyPress -= keyPress;
comboBox1.KeyUp -= keyUp;
```

Comment: It is not as simple as using var, use Sanjeevakumar's methods and -= those.

Comment: Or use `e.Handled = someBoolVar` where someBoolVar has the state of enabled/disabled.

Comment: how do i reset the height of the DropDownHeight?  Should i store the height initially? and reset it to that when i want to re-enable?

Comment: you could do that or create a combo with a lot of items, and see what is the maximum; DropDownHeight is set to that.

Answer (score 0):

In the GotFocus hander (whatever it is called), set the focus to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, not good enough.  Make it disabled and look *exactly* like the original so the user is completely fooled.  Add a new class and paste this code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class FakeComboBox : ComboBox {
    private PictureBox fake;
    public new bool Enabled {
        get { return base.Enabled; }
        set { if (!this.DesignMode) displayFake(value);
              base.Enabled = value;
        }
    }
    private void displayFake(bool enabled) {
        if (!enabled) {
            fake = new PictureBox();
            fake.Location = this.Location;
            fake.Size = this.Size;
            var bmp = new Bitmap(fake.Size.Width, fake.Size.Height);
            this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
            fake.Image = bmp;
            this.Parent.Controls.Add(fake);
            fake.BringToFront();
            fake.Click += delegate { Console.Beep(); };
        }
        else {
            this.Parent.Controls.Remove(fake);
            fake.Dispose();
            fake = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The very slight 'glow' you get on Win7 when you re-enable it is very interesting.

Comment: Haha, fantastic. As absurd as this is, it's still a much better solution than setting the DropDownHeight to 0.

Comment: When this control is enabled you try setting enabled again. This code tries to dispose `fake` which is null. and throws up exception. Secondly it still looks greyed, any theme changes have to be handled if it has to look like an enabled combo.